# MySQL 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1052

How can I correct the problem I keep getting from the code below which states `'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous`. Thanks for the help in advance.

Here is the mysql table.

```
SELECT user.*, user_info.* 
FROM user 
INNER JOIN user_info ON user.user_id = user_info.user_id
WHERE user_id=1
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You simply need to specify which `user_id` to use, since both the `user_info` and `user` table have a field called `user_id`:

```
... WHERE user.user_id=1
```

SQL wouldn't tolerate this ambiguity, since for what it knows, both fields can represent totally different data.

Comment: But what If both table have same field name like 'create_at' in both tables? And we do not specify it in where clause and we want to fetch the field from both tables with same method user.* and user_info.*

Comment: So, in my case there where clause 'some_field' was missing the table name. like `table_name.some_field`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to select each column explicitly everywhere.  Don't use user.* and user_info.* in your select list, either:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_fudge, ui.foo, ui.bar
FROM user u
INNER JOIN user_info ui
    ON ui.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: This isn't really a correct solution to the problem, it just relies on selecting a single user_id column to resolve the ambiguity. I personally prefer the more general solution of specifying the table in the WHERE clause, i.e. `WHERE u.user_id = '$user_id'`

Answer (score 0):

You should be mention alias name of your column and assign to user_id like

```
SELECT user.*, user_info.* 
FROM user as u 
INNER JOIN user_info as ui ON u.user_id = ui.user_id
WHERE u.user_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same error and i have resolved it by change:

```
var extra = 'AND (STATUS = 1 OR STATUS IS NULL)';
```

to

```
var extra = 'AND (ORDW.STATUS = 1 OR ORDW.STATUS IS NULL)';
```

When i join more than 2 tables.