# subquery: on clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
    `lecture` AS l
)
LEFT JOIN  `professor` AS p ON  `p`.`professor_id` =  `l`.`professor_id` 
WHERE  `lecture_sem` =  '20141'
AND (
    lecture_name LIKE  '%KEYWORD%'
    OR lecture_code LIKE  '%KEYWORD%'
    OR p.professor_name LIKE  '%KEYWORD%'
)
AND (
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT s1.yoil, s1.start_time, s1.end_time ) 
    FROM schedule AS s1
    INNER JOIN schedule AS s2 ON ( s1.lecture_id
    IN (
        SELECT lecture_id
        FROM timeitem
        WHERE timetable_id =890
    )
AND s2.yoil = s1.yoil
AND (
    (
    s1.start_time <= s2.start_time
    AND s2.end_time <= s1.end_time
    ) ) 
    AND s2.lecture_id = lecture_id # <-- HERE
    )
) >0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I want to use where column like this:

```
s2.lecture_id = lecture_id
```

or,

```
s2.lecture_id = l.lecture_id
```

So I want to use parent column in subquery, but error occurs:

```
Column 'lecture_id' in on clause is ambiguous
```

I googled many answers about this problem ("on clause is ambiguous"), they said I should replace this query to joining two queries. But I don't have a clue how to transform this query.

Comment: See if this is related or a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788326/mysql-user-id-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following does the equivalent query, but I haven't tested it.

The technique is to move the correlated subquery into the FROM clause as a *derived table* so that it gets run only once, producing a result for each lecture_id (hence the GROUP BY).

I also factored out the subquery for timetable, which I believe can be rewritten as a JOIN.

And I suspect the join to professor may be properly an INNER JOIN -- how can you have a lecture without a professor?

```
SELECT l.*, p.*
FROM lecture AS l
INNER JOIN professor AS p ON  p.professor_id =  l.professor_id 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s2.lecture_id, COUNT( DISTINCT s1.yoil, s1.start_time, s1.end_time ) AS count
    FROM schedule AS s1
    INNER JOIN schedule AS s2 ON s2.yoil = s1.yoil 
        AND s1.start_time <= s2.start_time AND s2.end_time <= s1.end_time
    INNER JOIN timeitem AS t ON s1.lecture_id = t.lecture_id
    WHERE t.timetable_id = 890
    GROUP BY s2.lecture_id
) AS c ON l.lecture_id = c.lecture_id
WHERE l.lecture_sem =  '20141' 
    AND c.count > 0 
    AND (
        l.lecture_name LIKE  '%KEYWORD%'
        OR l.lecture_code LIKE  '%KEYWORD%'
        OR p.professor_name LIKE  '%KEYWORD%'
    )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Anyway, even if the query isn't perfect, it demonstrates how one would refactor it to avoid a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The line you identified in your code isn't an `ON` clause.

Instead, I think the error is referring to the following section.

```
AND (
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT s1.yoil, s1.start_time, s1.end_time ) 
    FROM schedule AS s1
    INNER JOIN schedule AS s2 ON ( s1.lecture_id
    IN (
        # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        SELECT lecture_id # <---- HERE
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        FROM timeitem
        WHERE timetable_id =890
    )
```

You can fix this by creating an alias for the `timeitem` table, and prefixing the column with this prefix:

```
IN (
  SELECT ti.lecture_id 
  FROM timeitem as ti
  WHERE ti.timetable_id =890
)
```

But as Bill Karwin pointed out in his answer, you have other logical issues that need to be addressed.