# Column 'product_code' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT rm_item_cost.product_code, SUM(rm_item_cost.cost) AS rm_cost, SUM(dm_item_cost.cost) AS dm_cost, SUM(labour_item_cost.cost) AS labour_cost, SUM(overheads_item_cost.cost) AS o_cost 
FROM rm_item_cost 
INNER JOIN dm_item_cost ON dm_item_cost.product_code = rm_item_cost.product_code 
INNER JOIN labour_item_cost ON labour_item_cost.product_code = dm_item_cost.product_code 
INNER JOIN overheads_item_cost ON overheads_item_cost.product_code = labour_item_cost.product_code 
WHERE product_code = 'CMRO-01'
```

Comment: Remove the ambiguity. Otherwise, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please ask a question and do not post code only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 'user\_id' in where clause is ambiguous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788326/mysql-user-id-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous-problem)

Answer (score 2):

You have miore than one column named `product_code` in the tables you select from, so you have to add an alias to tell mysql which column you mean:

```
WHERE rm_item_cost.product_code = 'CMRO-01'
```